# Passing variables to UnrealEngine from an .swf (and vice versa)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d, air, unreal-engine4

I'm working on a project along with 3D developers. I'm an Actionscript developer doing the front end (2D) controls for a 3D game.

- The 3D game is on one screen and the 2D controls are on another
- Both the 3D game and the 2D controls are running locally on the same machine
- The 2D controls are in an Air application on a touch screen while the 3D game is in Unreal Engine on a bigger, non-touch screen

The 3D developers are working on the game itself in UE4's blueprint 'visual coding' thing.

How can I pass variables back and forth between the .swf and the Unreal game?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're several possibilities.

- [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html). You simply write to the file while UE reads this file and vice versa.
- [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html). In this case you can read and write to standart input/output.
- [ServerSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ServerSocket.html). This is the most preferable way. Your AIR application will act as a server while a game will connect to it. You simply pass TCP messages back and forth. You can use JSON or Protobuf for messages encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was beginning to consider using Text files and going back and forth by reading/writing text files every frame.

Which, of course, is slow as hell.

Comment: I ended up using the ServerSocket and it works great. Thank you again for your help.